# Open txt file with default program

Tags: c++, qt, directory, default

In my program, I have a button that I want to open a text file in a relative directory. I'm using QDesktopServices like this:

```
QDesktopServices::openUrl(QUrl::fromLocalFile("file:///stuff/block_settings.txt"));
```

When the button is pressed, nothing happens.

The file is in a folder named "stuff" that resides in the same location as my .exe. It is the same directory used for all my other tasks.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Is there no way of requesting failure status for  `QDesktopServices::openUrl()`?  The first rule of debugging is fetch and read the error message.

Comment: I got ShellExecute '/stuff/block_settings.txt' failed (error 2) false

Comment: `QUrl::fromLocalFile("file:///stuff/block_settings.txt”)` - that’s prepending file:// twice. Either use `QUrl("file:///stuff/block_settings.txt”)` or `QUrl::fromLocalFile("/stuff/block_settings.txt”)`

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I fixed the issue. Changed to:

```
QDesktopServices::openUrl(QUrl("file:stuff\\block_settings.txt"));
```

Not sure how that works because I don't see that configuration on any tutorial anywhere but w/e

Comment: I do not understand this answer. Can you please provide the snippet where "file:foo\bar.txt" made it working?

Comment: I still do not see any documentation reference or at least code, etc. I am not sure where you got this information from.

Comment: so, why not do things that in the documentation then, like QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath? What guarantees this will be working in a couple of months?

Comment: Why would anything be different from now in a couple months?

Comment: because there is no any guarantee for it being stable. It does not look like a documented API. I would personally delete this post as it is even misleading.

Comment: It's been working fine for close to a year now... so I guess not.

Comment: Omitting double slashes for `file` URI-scheme is not a standard, but a widely [supported](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme#Meaning_of_slash_character) practice.

Answer (score 1):

> The file is in a folder named "stuff" that resides in the same location as my .exe. It is the same directory used for all my other tasks. What am I doing wrong?

Seems like your full path is an overcomplication. I would suggest to use this intead:

> [QString QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath() [static]](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/qdoc/qcoreapplication.html#applicationDirPath)
>
> Returns the directory that contains the application executable.
>
> For example, if you have installed Qt in the C:\Qt directory, and you run the regexp example, this function will return "C:/Qt/examples/tools/regexp".
>
> On Mac OS X this will point to the directory actually containing the executable, which may be inside of an application bundle (if the application is bundled).
>
> Warning: On Linux, this function will try to get the path from the /proc file system. If that fails, it assumes that argv[0] contains the absolute file name of the executable. The function also assumes that the current directory has not been changed by the application.

So, you would be writing this code:

```
QDesktopServices::openUrl(QString("%1/stuff/block_settings.txt")
                          .arg(QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath()));
```